# How to receive a zip file in koa server

Tags: node.js, koa

I'm implementing a webserver using Koa. One of my request handlers needs to receive and store a large zip file. The file is NOT uploaded from a web page, but sent from another NodeJs application. Therefore it's not multipart encoded, but just applcation/octet-stream. How can I read such a file from the request?
I've noticed there is a request.socket object but I could not find any documentation on how to use it.

In other words I need the opposite to 
`this.body = fs.createReadStream(path);`

Comment: `this.req` is a readable stream that you can pipe to anywhere.

Comment: @greim, I tried to do `var f = fs.createWriteStream('c:\\myOutput.zip'); this.req.pipe(f)` but nothing really happens